# C# Combobox, give focus to Popup on keydown

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I've created a class that inherits from Combobox, the class is editable. When a user have searched for a given predicate, I want them to be able to iterate the list with pressing the down key. This is somewhat implemented as it works sporadically. Is it any way to force focus to the popup element? I would like to do this by code, and not in XAML.

I've tried

```
var popup = Template.FindName("PART_Popup", this) as Popup;
popup.Focus();
```

Which return false as expected as this didn't work.

I've also tried

```
var s1 = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
            if (s1 is FrameworkElement)
            {
                ((FrameworkElement)s1).MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
            }
```

But this focus on the next element in the TAB stack.

This focus approach didn't work either,

```
Keyboard.Focus(popup);
```

## Edit:

I solved (achieved the desired effect) by setting the animation to .None, and then close followed by open the popup again.

Comment: Do you want to focus it right after creating the popup or later?

Comment: And also: Is there any control on this popup the focus could be set to?

Comment: I want the focus to happen when a given key on the keyboard is pressed. The popup is just a regular list of items either described by their toString() methods or DefinedName.